# Find out If index and table statistics are out of date

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing, statistics

I Update indexes with full scan weekly. so when I run:

```
SELECT name AS index_name,
STATS_DATE(OBJECT_ID, index_id) AS StatsUpdated
FROM sys.indexes
```

Ref: [link text](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/01/25/sql-server-find-statistics-update-date-update-statistics/#comment-60521)

I expect it to show me that all indexes were updated this weekend. But there are several records which look like:

```
index_name StatsUpdated
clust      2005-10-14 01:36:26.140
clust      2005-10-14 01:36:26.140
```

What does it mean?

And,
How do I know that the statistics are out of date ( if in case I need to update statistics with full scan more often)

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a name like "clust" they are probably system tables and indexes.

Add this filter to check:

```
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTYEX(object_id, 'IsSystemTable') = 0
```